# WPF Datagrid IsReadOnly Property Error

Tags: wpf

I defined datagrid in WPF, but i can't set the IsReadOnly Property in DataGridTextColumn and DataGrid

```
  <dg:DataGrid  SelectionUnit="FullRow"    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyleByGiri}"  ItemsSource="{Binding QueuedTradesCollection}"  Margin="20"                  
    AlternationCount="2" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}"

                 VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFADD8E6" 

                 HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFADD8E6" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Grid.RowSpan="1" x:Name="grdvw_trades" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}">

<dg:DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="true"     Header="Notional/PairOffAmount"   Width="120" ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" SortMemberPath="Notional"  DataFieldBinding="{Binding Notional,StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
```

I got the following error message "The property 'DataGridColumn.IsReadOnly' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor"

Comment: What is your dg namespace pointing to ? Is it the built in WPF datagrid you're using or a customization ? DataGridTextColumn.IsReadOnly normally has an accessible set accessor. On a side note, DataGridTextColumn are to be set in <DataGrid.Columns>

Comment: my dg namespace pointing to   xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit". Iam using built in wpf datagrid. I defined my columns inside the      <dg:DataGrid.Columns>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used WPF TOOLKIT 2008, IsReadonly Property exists only in WPF Datagrid.